# Javascript for loop var "i" is treated as a string?

Tags: javascript, titanium

I am using Titanium to build some mobile apps and I noticed that this will give a result that I wasn't expecting.

```
data = ['a','b', 'c','d'];

for (var i in data){
    Ti.API.debug(i+1);
};
```

This will print: 01,11,12,13

Is this something particular to Titanium or is it generally in Javascript?

Why isn't 'i' being treated as an integer? I am very confused.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't you mean 01, 11, 21, 31?

Comment: What's your desired output? is it `1, 2, 3, 4` or `a1, b1, c1, d1` or something else?

Comment: More about `for..in` in JavaScript and how it can cause problems: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/

Comment: Yes. Sorry I meant 01,11,21,31,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but if you are looping through an array you should *not* use `for (var i in data)`. This loops through all *members* of an object, including methods, properties, etc.

What you want to do is this:

```
for (var i=0, item; i<data.length; i++) {
    item = data[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`data` is an array, so you use a `for` loop, not a `for-in` loop:

```
var data = [ ... ];
var i;

for ( i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1 ) {
    Ti.API.debug( i + 1 );
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array method:

```
data.forEach( function ( val, i ) {
    Ti.API.debug( i + 1 );
});
```

Comment: So the for-in loops are only supposed to be used for objects not arrays?

Comment: @LeonardoAmigoni Yes. However, I don't use `for-in` at all. When I want to iterate over the own properties of an object, I use `Object.keys( myObject ).forEach( ... );`. I do this instead `for-in`, because `for-in` also iterates over the inherited properties which is something that I don't want to do in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you see this behavior is that the type of `i` when using a `for-in` over an array is `string` not `int`.  Hence the `+` is doing string concatenation and not addition.  If you want it to be the numerical value then use a `for` loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  Ti.API.debug(i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = ['a','b', 'c','d'];

for (var i in data){
    Ti.API.debug(i*1+1);
};
```

Multiplying i x 1 will force it to recognize it as numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Ti.API.debug(parseInt(i)+1);
```

Comment: That's not true. A `for` loop iterates over property *names* of an object, not its values. And for an array, the property names are the indexes.

Comment: @FelixKling, good catch, I totally read that wrong!  Edited to not display an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
data = ['a','b', 'c','d'];

for (var i in data){
    console.log(parseInt(i)+1);
};
```

But it is not recommended. Because in Javascript `for..in` loop is for key:value pairs (Objects). So if use it with an array each index  is converted to string as key.

so always use `for(i = 0; i < length; i++)` with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is because javascript handles for-each loop this way.

In other languages **for(i in datas)** will loop through each data.

But in javascript the **i will have index value instead of data**. so you have to get data by **datas[i]**.