# Why does a "for ... in" loop—for (var/let/const A in B)—make A a string in vanilla ES6?

Tags: javascript

This is in Chromium 78:

```js
for (var i in [1,3,5]) console.log(i+1)
```

[image]

Now, I expected `for (var i in [1,3,5]) console.log(i+1)` to output 1, 2, 3, because `i` should be an index value.  I know [the MDN docs mention that the order may come out strangely in this case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), but why the type conversion?

Comment: `for...in` returns a string key. Also: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504)

Comment: To get the expected do `console.log(parseInt(i)+1)`

Comment: or just `console.log(+i+1)`

Comment: Checkout the "Array iteration and for...in" section of the manual, you referenced. There is the explanation.

Comment: Also see note section `for...in` should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important"

Comment: That's because an array is really just a special type of object and object keys are always strings.

Comment: `for ... in` iterates over property keys, which are (apart from symbols) always strings...

Comment: I know it outputs a string—see title—and I know it says order is not necessarily honoured—see my post.  My question was _why_.  I'm also not asserting this is a best practice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077537/for-in-loop-index-is-string-instead-of-integer , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479386/javascript-for-loop-counter-coming-out-as-string , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591317/javascript-for-loop-var-i-is-treated-as-a-string , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985421/variable-in-for-loop-is-a-string

Comment: Thanks @ASDFGerte, I had missed that, but "why" and "what are my options for workarounds" are two different questions, so I'm still glad to have the answer here.  I guess internally an Array converts its indexes back to integers before giving them back to users, but it still struck me as strange on the surface.

Comment: @Kev `Array#forEach` passes the index as a number to its callback: `[1, 3, 5].forEach((n, i) => console.log(i + 1));`

Comment: @Kev Actually it's the other way arround: Array internally converts the numbers (or anything really) into strings to access the property. `arr[5]` is basically `arr["5"]`. Try this: `[1, 2, 3][ { toString() { return "2"; } } ]`, first the object `{ toString() { return "2"; } }` is converted into a string which returns `"2"` which is the key of the third item in the array `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks for adding more.  None of these came up as suggestions when posting my original question, apparently too concisely formatted for my own good (and yet people still commented without seeming to have read what I wrote in its entirety.)

Comment: The much harsher problem with `for ... in` is, that unlike many other methods (e.g. `Object.keys`), it iterates the prototype chain aswell. Therefore, e.g. `Array.prototype["surprise!"] = 1; for (let p in []) console.log(p);` may be "surprise!"'ing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` is not the index, `i` is the property key of the array **object**. Property keys are always strings.